# tt_news marker "NEWS_CATEGORY" gives me parent category and all child category

Tags: typo3, marker, tt-news

I have the following news category structure

News
|-Category 1
|-Category 2
|-Category 3

I have made a TYPO3 update recently and now I'm experiencing that the marker `NEWS_CATEGORY` is printed in the following way

`News, Category 1, Category 2, Category 3`

The news article itselfs is assigned to the category news. How can I restrict this output to the category it is assigned (in this case News)? I don't know if it was the TYPO3 update (including tt_news update) or a configuration problem in my setup.

If I use `NEWS_CATEGORY_ROOTLINE` then I get something like `News > Category 2`. How can I output only the name of the selected category? The problem seems to only occur when the parent category is selected.

Answer (score 1):

When you update tt_news it's strongly suggested to also use the built-in update.  Tt_news recently updated also the table structure so you really need to follow the tt-news update instruction. It also makes it not compatible with older tt-news.

Comment: The relations seems to be correct. Only the output of the category name makes problem. Do you really think that the update has gone wrong?

Comment: I made the updater script described in [the tt_news manual](https://typo3.org/extension-manuals/tt_news/3.2.1/view/1/2/#id557641). Now the updater doesn't show any errors and the site seems to work despite I fixed `search for non existing HTML templates, Startingpoint and listlimit.` I still get the parent category with all it's subcategories ...

Comment: That's stange. Maybe you need to assign them again?

Comment: I removed the category, saved the news, added a new category and saved it again. Still the same problem. The assignement of the categories is correct. Only `tables` in `tt_news_cat_mm` is empty, but I don't think that's needed.

Comment: Did you delete the FE-cache? I know that the table structure is changed. That's why tt-news has this update-converter thing. Maybe you need a typoscript to activate categories?

Comment: I used `Clear all caches`. What do you mean with the TS? I have `useSubCategories = 1` and `displaySubCategories = 1` and `categoryMode = 1` but I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: That's what I mean. I don't know. I need to look into my installation.

Comment: I now set `displaySubCategories = 0` and I think it works. I'll have to test it a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

`displaySubCategories = 0` seems to do the trick.